# Select all records from MySQL table where specified time is reached or passed

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime

I have a table where I insert jobs that my user posts. I have a job_expiration column where I'm adding the job expiration time with

`now() + INTERVAL some DAY` like so.

I want to run a cron job to set the job status to late where the job_expiration is reached.

I have tried doing it `SELECT * FROM jobs WHERE status = 'active' AND job_expiration < NOW()` like so.

but it didn't worked.

here is how table looks like:

```
+----+------------+---------------------+--------+
| id | title      | job_expiration      | status |
+----+------------+---------------------+--------+
| 1  | something  | 2020-05-04 09:31:24 | active |
| 2  | something2 | 2020-06-01 06:06:58 | active |
+----+------------+---------------------+--------+
```

I want to select first row here.

how can I do that?

Comment: You should try job_expiration> DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 1 minute)

Comment: @nacho, it didn't worked. it is selecting all jobs

Comment: I cannot reproduce your issue.